# Civi 5.9 not serving extension javascript in WP 5

Tags: wordpress, extension, core

TLDR EDIT: 
  Civi getURL generated `<site>/civicrm/<resourcepath>?r=<key>` doesn't serve `<site>/<resourcepath>` Should the file be coming from civi with a key or not go through civi?

I have a fairly new LAMP machine with CiviCRM 5.9.1 installed in Wordpress 5.0.3 with the plugin installer.
I am getting a 404 when a contribution page is trying to pull in civicrm_stripe.js for the stripe payment processor.

I can load the file at `<site>/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/js/civicrm_stripe.js` (where I probably should get a 404) but get a 404 on `<site>/civicrm/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/js/civicrm_stripe.js?r=<key>`

Is there any way to see why the resource isn't being served?

Comment: Note also that CiviCRM 5.9.0 has some rather nasty bugs, you'll definitely want 5.9.1!

Comment: Good to know - I didn't see the latest release blog only does major releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SE!  Check your Extension Resource URL at `Administer > System Settings > Resource URL's`

A typical WP install would show the Extension Resource URL as `[civicrm.files]/ext` where `[civicrm.files]` is `https://example.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm`

Comment: I believe it is correct - the extension php is loading, but the when civi is asked to serve the resource it doesn't.  I guess specifically, CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addScriptFile('com.drastikbydesign.stripe', 'js/civicrm_stripe.js') is not working.

Comment: In the end I could get this to work by removing civi from the path and I'll hope that's right! :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress/CiviCRM can have trouble resolving tokens like `[civicrm.files]` if you have a symlink in your path.

If you're having resource URL issues, I recommend replacing the tokens with absolute paths (with no symlinks) in **Administer » System Settings » Directories** as well as checking **Administer » System Settings » Resource URLs** as Aidan suggests.  It sounds like your `CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL` is set correctly in `civicrm.settings.php` but it never hurts to check.

A permanent solution for this is underway: See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1497.

Comment: Jon, do you have a link to documentation (or issue queue) regarding "WordPress/CiviCRM can have trouble resolving tokens like [civicrm.files] if you have a symlink in your path."?

Comment: Can I link to this answer? :)  This is something I learned from Kevin C., who researched it extensively. I can't say for sure if it's documented anywhere else, but you can talk to him about the bloody details

Comment: Issue created, with reference to this SE question and to today's MM discussion with Kevin C. https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1497 (I suggest adding this to the answer for improved visibility).