# Stripe plugin not finding js and css files on contribution page

Tags: wordpress, stripe, payment

Wordpress and Civicrm hosted on siteground.com

This is the first ever install I've tried of the Stripe payment processor plugin.  (version 6.1.5 on wordpress)

Ensured MJWShared (v0.4.4) was first installed.

When viewing a contribution page with a stripe payment processor attached - the javascript files cannot be found in (404 error in the console.)

The files exist, but when looking at the Stripe Payment Processor extension in the civicrm extension manager the Local Path listed is

/home/customer/www/[myurl.com]/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe

and in the console - it is trying to retrieve the js and css files 
(civicrm_stripe.js, elements.css) using the path below as a base.

https://[myurl.com]/home/customer/www/[myurl.com]/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe

Has anyone come across this before? or have I done something stupid?

Comment: the url *should* be https://[myurl.com]/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/... Can you check if you have the correct extension url in your civicrm admin ?

Comment: Is your CiviCRM plugin directory symlinked by any chance?

Comment: @Xavier the extension resource url in civicrm is shown as [civicrm.files]/ext/

Comment: @ChristianWach unless I did it accidentally - I dont believe so.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing this question [Civi 5.9 not serving extension javascript in WP 5](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28272/civi-5-9-not-serving-extension-javascript-in-wp-5)

I put an absolute path in the resource URL in Administer > System Settings > Resource URL

and the issue was fixed.