# extension assets (js and css) being blocked: The resource was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch

Tags: extension, resource-urls

I've been troubleshooting a problem with our Stripe payment processor, and figured out that in fact extension scripts and style sheets are being blocked. Sample error:

```
The resource from “https://<domain>/civicrm_custom/extensions/mjwshared/js/crm.payment.js?r=rEd8ien_US” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)
```

Errors appear for js and css files in the extensions directory. However, CiviCRM itself is working fine, all js and css assets loading correctly. It's only the extensions that are being blocked.

Direct calls to the JS and CSS asset URLs also produce 404s.

I'm not sure exactly when this problem started; the last time we used the Stripe  extension was last March; CiviCRM and the processor extension have been upgraded since then. The site has not been moved.  I found [this entry](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28272/civi-5-9-not-serving-extension-javascript-in-wp-5) and I've looked at the Resource URL and directory settings and they are the same as previously (they are absolute paths).

Permissions for the directories have also not changed, and seem to be similar to the Civicrm directories.

I'm just a bit stumped as to why the extensions are being blocked, but not the main Civi?

What have I overlooked?  Thanks!

System deets:
Joomla 3.10.11
CiviCRM 5.55.2

Answer (score 1):

Color me stupid.  Found the problem:  firewall was blocking access to the extensions directory.  Not a Civi problem at all :-)